# Asymptotic analysis of algorithms problem

Tags: data-structures

Well, I came across a question that I could not solve can anyone tell how I can solve this problem. Not the definition but the mathematical problem.
[image: Asymptotoic analysis problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- express each time in microseconds, for example 1 sec = 10^6 microsec, let it be *t* (unclear for Month, perhaps it is considered 30 days?)
- find inverse function, i.e. *n* in *f(n)=t* equation, for example if *sqrt(n)=t* , then *n = t^2*
- substitute *t* (round down if not integer - all functions are increasing)
- for *n!* there is no simple inverse function, you can compute it numerically or partially help yourself using [inverse Stirling's approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078997/inverse-of-a-factorial).